# Swift 4: How to create a face map with ios11 vision framework from face landmark points

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, swift4

I am using the ios 11 vision framework to yield the face landmark points in real time. I am able to get the face landmark points and overlay the camera layer with the UIBezierPath of the face landmark points. However, I would like to get something like the bottom right picture. Currently I have something that looks like the left picture, and I tried looping through the points and adding midpoints, but I don't know how to generate all those triangles from the points. How would I go about generating the map on the right from the points on the left?

I'm not sure I can with all the points I have, not that it will help too much, but I also have points from the bounding box of the entire face. Lastly, is there any framework that would allow me to recognize all the points I need, such as openCV or something else, please let me know. Thanks!

[image: face_map]

Here is the code I've been using from https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/VisionFaceDetection:

```
func detectLandmarks(on image: CIImage) {
    try? faceLandmarksDetectionRequest.perform([faceLandmarks], on: image)
    if let landmarksResults = faceLandmarks.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {

        for observation in landmarksResults {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let boundingBox = self.faceLandmarks.inputFaceObservations?.first?.boundingBox {
                    let faceBoundingBox = boundingBox.scaled(to: self.view.bounds.size)
                    //different types of landmarks



                    let faceContour = observation.landmarks?.faceContour
                    self.convertPointsForFace(faceContour, faceBoundingBox)

                    let leftEye = observation.landmarks?.leftEye
                    self.convertPointsForFace(leftEye, faceBoundingBox)

                    let rightEye = observation.landmarks?.rightEye
                    self.convertPointsForFace(rightEye, faceBoundingBox)

                    let leftPupil = observation.landmarks?.leftPupil
                    self.convertPointsForFace(leftPupil, faceBoundingBox)

                    let rightPupil = observation.landmarks?.rightPupil
                    self.convertPointsForFace(rightPupil, faceBoundingBox)

                    let nose = observation.landmarks?.nose
                    self.convertPointsForFace(nose, faceBoundingBox)

                    let lips = observation.landmarks?.innerLips
                    self.convertPointsForFace(lips, faceBoundingBox)

                    let leftEyebrow = observation.landmarks?.leftEyebrow
                    self.convertPointsForFace(leftEyebrow, faceBoundingBox)

                    let rightEyebrow = observation.landmarks?.rightEyebrow
                    self.convertPointsForFace(rightEyebrow, faceBoundingBox)

                    let noseCrest = observation.landmarks?.noseCrest
                    self.convertPointsForFace(noseCrest, faceBoundingBox)

                    let outerLips = observation.landmarks?.outerLips
                    self.convertPointsForFace(outerLips, faceBoundingBox)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

func convertPointsForFace(_ landmark: VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D?, _ boundingBox: CGRect) {
    if let points = landmark?.points, let count = landmark?.pointCount {
        let convertedPoints = convert(points, with: count)



        let faceLandmarkPoints = convertedPoints.map { (point: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)) -> (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) in
            let pointX = point.x * boundingBox.width + boundingBox.origin.x
            let pointY = point.y * boundingBox.height + boundingBox.origin.y

            return (x: pointX, y: pointY)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.draw(points: faceLandmarkPoints)
        }
    }
}


func draw(points: [(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)]) {
    let newLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    newLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    newLayer.lineWidth = 4.0

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y))
    for i in 0..<points.count - 1 {
        let point = CGPoint(x: points[i].x, y: points[i].y)
        path.addLine(to: point)
        path.move(to: point)
    }
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y))
    newLayer.path = path.cgPath

    shapeLayer.addSublayer(newLayer)
}
```

Comment: Not to be flippant, but what makes you think you *can*? Just looking at the forehead, you have *zero* points detected (which suonds about right from my tests) and yet you think you can *eighteen* triangles?

Comment: @dfd I have updated my question to reflect your concern.

Comment: At best, the bounding box will give you 4 more points. I've been playing with face details from this GitHub (https://github.com/artemnovichkov/iOS-11-by-Examples) and every face with hair I use has nothing from the forehead up. A few thoughts, probably not much help: (1) Best OpenCV/OpenGL, or CoreImage/CoreGraphics, you might be able to analyze things in a way to decipher the hairline and/or cheekbones by color. But thats making a lot of assumptions, including no bangs or long hair, and proper lighting. (2) Another possibility is machine learning - training your own model and using CoreML.

Comment: A followup on CoreML. I'm no expert on ML by a long shot, but have dabbled in it. A trained model that can distinguish haircuts versus hairlines, eyeglasses, facial hair, etc. *may* be possible. Hopefully there may be something out there! Otherwise, you may have your work cut out for you. Good luck.

Comment: @dfd Thank you for your help. I will play around with different libraries and see what gives my what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Ali did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ali have you find any solution for this case? i want to make a map of the face like the image on the right side.

Comment: @R.AlAli see my answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did end up finding a solution that works. I used delaunay triangulation via https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/DelaunaySwift, and I modified it to work with the points generated via the vision framework's face landmark detection request. This is not easily explained with a code snippet, so I have linked my github repo below that shows my solution. Note that this doesn't get the points from the forehead, as the vision framework only gets points from the eyebrows down.

https://github.com/ahashim1/Face

Comment: Do you have an idea as to why the mask lags behind the input by a couple of frames? If you point me in the right direction I can play around with it and make a PR.

Comment: @AdityaGarg I think it's because the face landmark request is done asynchronously while the triangles are drawn on the main thread. Not quite sure how to completely synchronize the processes. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

What you want in the image on the right is a [Candide](http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/) mesh. You need to map these points to the mesh and that will be it. I don't think you need to go the route that has been discussed in the comments.

P.S I found Candide while going through the APK contents of a famous filters app(reminds me of casper) - haven't had the time to try it myself yet.